# There is already an object named 'xxx' in the database

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework Core and doing migration. Since my program is purely development stage, how do I force the migration (overwrite the existing db scheme)? I tried with command `add-migration someText` and `update-database` but no success.

Comment: You want to rebuild your database from scratch again ?

Comment: No. i just want to make changes to the database. I don't need to check the database . Just need to overwrite whatever changes to the database.

Comment: How *no success*? That's exactly what migrations should do.

Comment: I got the above error message

Comment: Can you share the error message ? I think you want to change a migration and run it again, right ?

Comment: If I removed the database, and rerun the migration, it works. Just that sometimes, I hit `There is already an object named 'xxx' in the database` and I don't want to always remove the database.

Comment: Can you should your migration code? All of them.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up because you probably have migration that includes table, column same like in one of previous migrations. Check every migration if there is no some duplicates. It sometimes happen when you revert your snapshot file. If you want more help with this issue you will need provide more information about your migrations and schema.

Comment: If you use the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" option and then choose "Code First from Database". Choose just one table. Then add extra column to that model class. Then `add-migration xxx` and `update-database`, this error will occur.